# Creating constructor for class

Tags: java, constructor

I've been trying to figure this out for awhile, it seems that I can't call the parrot in this class.

```
class Bird {
boolean f;
parrot Bird[];
int x;
}
```

I can't add any variables inside the class Bird anymore, I've tried putting it in a constructor, but there's always a red line under it.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: No, I have no idea what you're doing wrong - because you haven't explained what the problem is.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: `parrot Bird[];` this line is wrong, swap the words.

Comment: When you are declaring variables, the variable name goes _after_ the variable type. E.g. `Bird[] parrot` not `parrot Bird[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your class this way:

```
class Bird {
    boolean f;
    Bird[] parrot;
    int x;
}
```

(you changed the order of the type and the name of the attribute)

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to create your own class (I suppose since you have not provided full information on your `Client` class).

However, the problem I think is because of the lack of constructor in your `Bird` class. Since you dont declare any constructor in your `Bird` class, Java will automatically take default constructor from `Object` (which is the biggest class that contains everything else).

To create a constructor for your Bird Class do as follow:

```
class Animal {
    boolean f;
    Bird[ ] parrot;
    int x;

    public Animal() {
        this(false,inputParrot,inputX);
    }

    public Animal (boolean inputF, Bird[ ] inputParrot, int inputX) {
        f= inputF;
        parrot = new Bird[ ];
        parrot = inputParrot;
        x = inputX;
    }
}
```

I changed the name of your class as I assume you are trying to create a tree of `Animal`. Hence the order will be, `Animal` has-a `Bird`, `Bird` has-a `Parrot` (research on has-a and is-a relationship if you are unsure).